# Chrome Extension - If a page is requested, show a question before loading it

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to build a page blocker for digital detox. I want that the extension ask before loading the page that if I'm sure that i want to see the page. On affirmative, then load the page, if negative, then close the tab.

I should behave similar to unsecure site warning screen, but i can´t replicate that exactly.

Most of tutorials just put an overlay some secs after page is loaded, but i do not want to se any of the page.

There is my code

manifest.json

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "¿Estás seguro?",
  "description": "Te pregunta si estás seguro para entrar a una página",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["scripts/content.js"],
      "matches": [
        "https://*/*",
        "http://*/*"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "background": {
    "persistent": true,
    "page": "background.js"
  }
}
```

background.js

```js
const unwantedDomains = [
    'facebook.com'
];



chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
    function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

      // read changeInfo data and do something with it
      // like send the new url to contentscripts.js
      console.log(`onUpdate [${tabId} ${JSON.stringify(changeInfo)} ${JSON.stringify(tab)}]`);
      if (tab.url) {
        console.log(`valid [${tabId} ${changeInfo.url}]`);
        if (unwantedDomains.some(domain => tab.url.includes(domain))) {
          chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
            message: 'hello!',
            url: tab.url
          });
        }
      }
    }
  );


chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if(message.closeThis) chrome.tabs.remove(sender.tab.id);
});
```

scripts/content.js

```js
let block;

function removeBlock() {
    block.remove();
}

function closeCurrentTab() {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({closeThis: true});
}


chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {

    block = document.createElement('div');
    block.style.position = 'fixed';
    block.style.top = '0';
    block.style.left = '0';
    block.style.width = '100%';
    block.style.height = '100%';
    block.style.zIndex = '1000000000';

    //add a background color to the div

    document.body.appendChild(block);


    const text = document.createElement('p');
    block.appendChild(text);

    text.innerHTML = '¿Are you sure?';

    //add a button to the div
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    block.appendChild(button);

    button.innerHTML = `Yes`;

    const cancel = document.createElement('button');
    block.appendChild(cancel);

    cancel.innerHTML = 'No';

    //add an event listener to the button

    button.addEventListener('click', removeBlock);

    cancel.addEventListener('click', closeCurrentTab);

});
```